# Script for counting lines in sections excluding #

Tags: linux, bash

I'm searching for ideas to have a script doing the following:

I have a textual file eg. `test.txt` with the similar text in it:

```
#
# sectione 1
#
several
text
lines 
and so on
#
# sectione 2
#
more text
and more
#
and more
# ...
#
# sectione 3
#
more
more
more 
#
# sectione 4
#
...
...
```

I need a possibility to count only the lines in sectione 2 and exclude lines starting with #

In my above example the script should show me a counter with "3" at the end
eg.

```
# counter_script.sh test.txt 
# 3
```

Is this possibility and how can i do it?
I'm using Debian Linux with bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/sectione/{f=$3==2?1:0}f&&!/^#/{c++}END{print c}' file
```

Explanation in a multiline version:

*section2.awk:*

```
/sectione/ {
    # Set f(ound) to 1 (true) if the number between 'sectione' is a 2
    # otherwise 0 (false)
    f=$3==2?1:0
}

# If f(ound) is true (1) and the line starts not with a #
# count it
f&&!/^#/{
    c++
}

# At the end of input print the c(ount)
END{
    print c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will only look for (sectione 2) section count. Try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '/sectione 3/{a=""}/sectione 2/{a=1;next} !/#/ && a{count++} END{print count}'   Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Adding one more solution on same too now.

```
awk '/sectione 2/,/sectione 3/{count=$0!~/#/?++count:count} END{print count}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
sed -n '/# sectione 2/,/# sectione 3/{/^#/d;//!p;}' file | wc -l
```

`/# sectione 2/,/# sectione 3/` Selecting the lines between the section 2 and section 3

`/^#/d` deleting the lines starting with #

`//!p` printing the rest..

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/sectione 2/,/sectione 3/{/^#/!p}' test.txt | wc -l
```

Process the data between sectione 2 and sectione 3 pattern matching for # at the start of the line and then printing any lines that don't meet this pattern with !p.